# htaccess URL's redirect 301 to lowercase with exceptions

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to change all my URL's with lowercase using `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` in my Apache config file an in my htaccess have this regular expression:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

.. and work purfectly! But i have Libraries (with files) and Directories who i don't want to change to lowercase (for example: "Images" with all sub directories or Libraries: "Functions/Liberties/Image/Resize.php") ... how to make it?
I tried with `RewriteRule ^(Images) - [NC,QSA,L]` but don't accept it ... any idea how to make this exceptions?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: Add more RewriteConds that check that the REQUEST_URI is _not_ one of those you don’t want to rewrite.

Comment: May be you have more rules below this. Better to use `THE_REQUEST` in a `RewriteCond` to exclude your matching patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all ... i fix it with this:

```
RewriteRule ^Admin/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Apps/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Bank/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Downloads/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Functions/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Images/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Pages/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Scripts/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^Styles/ - [L]
```

... and i put it before:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

For me and my case work, i hope it is the right decision. Thank you again!

Comment: With this whenever you add a new file or folder, you will have to edit . htaccess again.

Answer (score 1):

You can first disable directory listing using `-indexes` and now, if the requested URI is an existing directory or a file, you can skip the rewrite rule using `!-d` and `!-f` params like below:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```